# Running Selenium Tests from a VSTS Hosted Agent

Tags: selenium, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am running the Selenium test in Visual Studio Team Services with VS2017 hosted agents, but I think I am having issue's with company's proxy.

I am running the Selenium test from Visual Studio 2015, it runs very fine and able to access the web application.

When I am running the same Selenium test in VSTS using hosted agents, then it is failing on the below error and not able to reach the URL of the application to be tested:
**"The site can't be reached"**

I know there are proxy authentication required in my company but I am not sure how to run the Selenium test from VSTS hosted agent which can bypass the proxy.

If someone know the answer, please respond

Comment: Is the site you're testing accessible from the internet?

Comment: Its internal site which is not accessible from internet, Selenium test is working fine when running from Visual studio and to connect the Visual studio with VSTS, I need to change the proxy in LAN settings, that's a work around. I believe that's the same problem for VSTS hosted agent that it's not able to make the connection. But I want to know where I can change the proxy settings. Also I have downloaded the agent to run from machine, but its showing the same error while connecting to VSTS, "Failed to connect"

Comment: @Rahul your issue could only be an incorrect PAT token- if you can access vsts from a browser on the machine you're attempting to install the agent on, you should not have any networking issue... we've never had to open any wild ports for this

Comment: It's unclear to me where your proxy lives and the configuration of said proxy. Do you need to authenticate to the proxy to hit VSTS from your browser, and what about the browser from the machine you install the agent on?

Comment: @Rahul You should use Selenium web drivers on Hosted agent. More details, you can refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/test/continuous-test-selenium?view=vsts#decide-how-you-will-deploy-and-test-your-app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hosted agent is run by Microsoft and exists in Azure. It does not have connectivity to your internal network where your site is hosted.

You will need to set up a private agent that exists within your local network. A proxy can be configured for a private agent during setup with the following command line: `./config.cmd --proxyurl http://127.0.0.1:8888 --proxyusername "1" --proxypassword "1"`

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/agents/proxy?view=vsts&tabs=windows

Comment: Hi again, I have downloaded the private agent from Agent pool of VSTS and trying to add the url of our VSTS project and Access token but still it's showing the error on prompt as below:   >> Connect:

Enter server URL > https://{project}.visualstudio.com
Enter authentication type (press enter for PAT) >
Enter personal access token > **************************************************
**
An error occurred while sending the request.
Failed to connect.

Comment: Also is it possible somehow hosted agent can have connectivity to internal network by proxy authentication which can possibly be done by networking team? What all inputs may require in order to establish the connection in this case?

Comment: @Rahul No, the hosted agent cannot be configured to use a proxy.

Comment: Okay, can you please share your answer on configuration of private agent using proxy authorization?

Comment: No need for a proxy if it's hosted internally

Comment: @KyleBurkett The proxy is ostensibly needed for internet connectivity to talk to VSTS.

Comment: @Daniel, I have tried configuring the agent with the proxy method as mentioned in the below link:                                                             
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/agents/proxy view=vsts&tabs=windows. Also I am following the same process to configure the agent as mentioned:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=vsts                                                         In both the cases it's Failed to connect, is Network or IT team need to open the port for this connection.

Answer (score 1):

We have several groups of agents hosted internally that can access stuff hosted on premise. We configured the agents using PAT's by clicking on user profile > security and generating a new PAT.

Comment: I have followed the same process, trying to configure the VSTS agent using Powershell with the VSTS project url and correct PAT but after taking some time, its says Failed to connect. I have tried with the proxy method while configuring the agent but it's not setting up the connection.